# Argument is not getting mapped in REST endpoint method in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-viewsets

I have following code in my `MyModuleViewSet`:

```
class MyModuleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    # ... 

    @action(detail=False, permission_classes=(IsOwnerOrReadOnly,))
    @debugger_queries
    def my_rest_api(self, request, pk=None):
        
        # ...

        return HttpResponse(resp, content_type="application/json", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

It is registered in my `urls.py` as follows:

```
router.register(r'mymodule', MyModuleViewSet)
```

I tried to hit this end point with following link:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/myproject/api/mymodule/1019/my_rest_api/?format=json&param1=7945
```

But it gave error saying:

```
Page not found (404)
   Request Method:  GET
   Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:3000/myproject/api/mymodule/1019/my_rest_api/?format=json&param1=7945

Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
  1. ...
  2. ...
     ... 
  37. courseware/ api/ ^mymodule/my_rest_api/$ [name='mymodule-my-rest-api']
  38. courseware/ api/ ^mymodule/my_rest_api\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='mymodule-my-rest-api']
  ...
```

As you can see `mymodule/my_rest_api` is indeed specified in the response on line 37 and 38. So, I tried with different url by removing `/1019`:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/myproject/api/mymodule/1019/my_rest_api/?format=json&param1=7945
```

and it hit the breakpoint inside the rest endpoint method. I was thinking that `1019` will get assigned to `pk` argument inside `my_rest_api(self, request,pk=None)`. But that did not happen. Why is this the case? Did I miss some basic understanding of how DRF works?

Comment: you are sending query_params not id this is how you'r sending query_parmas

Comment: Can you please tell how do I send query para?

Comment: you are already sending query parms, and one more thing is that your question isn;t detail explanation what you are going to do exactly and what type of response you want

Answer (score 0):

if your action looks like this

`@action(detail=False, permission_classes=(IsOwnerOrReadOnly,))`

your url can't be `http://0.0.0.0:3000/myproject/api/mymodule/1019/my_rest_api/`

set `detail=True` and add pk in `def my_rest_api(self, pk, request):`

or remove id from your url to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/myproject/api/mymodule/my_rest_api/`